# Jquery Mulitple select field error

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have multiple select field each with multiple options.
So, by using jquery to get the respective selected options content, I would be able to get the selected option content. However, this work for the first select field. But, does not work for others. Others keep referencing the first select field selected options content, instead of it owns. Please guide me! Thanks!

```
My Select fields

<select id="resource_dd" name="resource_dd">
    <option selected="selected" value="nil1">No resources.</option>
    <option value="1">Week1</option>
    <option value="2">Resource1</option>
</select>


<select id="module_dd" name="module_dd">
    <option selected="selected" value="nil2">No restriction.</option>
    <option value="1">IT1234</option>
    <option value="2">IT2345</option>
</select>
```

Jquery to retrieve the selected content.

```
$("#module_dd").change(function ( event ) {
    var option = $("this").children();
    var module_id = $(option+":selected").val(); //module_id get 'nil1' as content instead of nil2

});
```

Comment: So many problems in this code...do read all answers and apply them no matter which one you decide to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this, it will give you the selected value.

```
$("#module_dd").change(function ( event ) {
  var module_id = $(this).val(); 
});
```

Comment: +1 Indeed, no need to over-complicate. I suspect, however, that this is a reduced case and that he's doing other things regarding the select element.  Either way, though, you are correct that there is no need to discover which option is selected if all he wants is its value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be saying `$(this)` instead of `$("this")`.

Second, `$(event.target)` is probably more appropriate here.

Third, using `.children` as in `$(event.target).children(":selected")` will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem code**

```
var option = $("this").children();
var module_id = $(option+":selected").val();
```

You can't concat a selector string to a jQ collection object.  You need to filter the option collection for those which are selected either by:

```
var option = $( this ).children(":selected");
```

Or

```
var option = $( this ).children();
var module_id = option.filter(":selected").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are referencing `$("#module_dd")`.

You need to add another function and change that to `$("#resource_dd")` to get the other `select` field.

Comment: `#module_id` is the one which has an option with value, `nil2`, and I believe that's the value he is after...

Answer (score 0):

Please see Eli Courtwright's answer, but in addition to that, you should do something like `$("select")` or `$("#module_dd, #resource_dd")` to target both `select` fields.